# How can I poke a hole in the roof in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm making my underground farm in a new fortress, and I thought I would try a new way of getting water to it, going UNDER a lake.

I assumed I would just have to mine under it and the water would fall through. But of course I forgot the floor of the level above.

My question is simple: How can I poke a hole in my roof?

For a another view of the issue, here are some pics.

#### Level 1

[image: Level 1]

#### Level 0

[image: Level 0]

Comment: It might be easier to go back a square, then build up-steps and mine out the lake's wall. Either way have a look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/whats-the-deal-with-upward-stairways-in-dwarf-fortress), it could be useful. Don't forget some kind of door or flood gate in case the lake has too much water for you. And make sure the dwarf mining the final stage isn't someone important. But it's been a while since I've played DF, so I'm not too hot on the game at the moment.

Comment: thats quite a good idea, thanks! ill look over the link.

yeah i have a floorgate there its just open currently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Build an upward ramp on the square you want open the ceiling on, then go up a level and order that square channeled out. They should be able to reach it at that point.

If that doesn't work, building an upward stair and then telling them to dig the downward stair on the square above will.

Of course, either way whoever does the actual digging is going to get hurt when a lake's worth of water hits him right in the face...

Comment: Thats what Urist McRandomNoble is for!

Comment: Note that *building* an upward ramp will behave different than *digging* one in this case. Building a ramp does not remove the ceiling automatically; digging one does (and lets the water in).

Comment: No, but you'll need to build the ramp to get /to/ the ceiling so you can dig it out.

Comment: R.I.P Urist McMainMiner. He live a short but bright life at "Prison Bog"

Comment: His selfless sacrifice will be long remembered wherever a dorf hefts a tankard of proper Dwarven Ale...

Comment: Wouldn't a door right on the digging area help?