# Unflood Areas Within Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Well in my wisdom I've managed to flood a rather large section of my fortress by accident whilst digging a moat. I've managed to isolate the area, however, I'd quite like to unflood this area and repair the damage, is this possible?

It's flooded with water from a river, in my haste I forgot that water can leak diagonally [image: Diagram Showing The Issue]

Update: The accepted answer worked, however, I lost so many dwarves they couldn't fight off an elven invasion that followed shortly after. Sad times.

Comment: What's the area flooded with?

Comment: Edited accordingly :)

Comment: Was hoping the answer would be magma. More !fun!

Comment: Is the area actually connected to the infinite water source that is the river, or did you get water out of it using pumps?

Comment: Unfortunately the river... As you can tell, I'm pretty new to DF

Comment: That makes things difficult. If you could plug the leak, getting the water out would be fairly simple. I'll read some stuff and see if there's an easy way but you might be better off walling that bit off and rebuilding it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, there's nothing I could work out through googling. I could quite easily rebuild it but the aesthetics would annoy me way too much so if I can fix it I'd quite like to :P I'm going to try building a U/D stairway column on the first square of the leak down to a massive cavern and see if it all drains down there, then I'll plug it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. The river is infinite. You'll end up with a river flowing into the caverns and destroying your frame rate

Comment: Ahh ok, you answered that just before I opened it up, so thanks, I could always put a floodgate at the bottom so I can close it once its drained?

Comment: That'd work. I'll write up the whole process into an answer.

Comment: Just realised- the up/down stairs won't actually make a hole in the floor. You'll need to approach the flooded area from the side and dig a channel where one of the walls is.

Comment: Apparently you can poke a hole in the roof using the method outline [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25073/how-can-i-poke-a-hole-in-the-roof-in-dwarf-fortress) but I'll use your method if it doesn't work!

Comment: Digging from the side is probably safer.

Comment: Where's the Fun in safety? ;) plus, I'm not sure it's even possible to from the current trench arrangements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it might be easier to wall that section up and dig out some new rooms.

Since it's connected to an infinite water source, pumping it out isn't going to work- it'll just flow back in. Instead, give the water somewhere to go. Water can flow off the edges of cavern levels, so we'll use those.

Dig a shaft down to the caverns directly underneath one of the walls of the flooded area. Approach the flooded area from the side (make sure you can seal that tunnel) and dig a channel above the shaft.

You may need to make the shaft larger than 1x1 or dig multiple shafts so the water flows out faster than it can flow in.

Once most of the water has gone, you can put floodgates in to block the leak. Expect to get a lot of job cancellations here- a single tick where the area has 2/7 water will make it too dangerous- but eventually it will work.

Now that the leak is plugged, the water will continue to flow into the caverns until it's all drained. You can block the shaft at this point (or use it to dump rubbish).

You might want to build a new floor for the flooded area. Since it'll be muddy from all the water, you'll get mushrooms if you don't.